# Get index of Basemap where raycast hit occurred

Tags: unity

Initially I thought questions like [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/trying-to-get-color-of-a-pixel-on-texture-with-raycasting.608431/), showing how to get the index on a material's main texture from a raycast hit would be the answer

Experimenting with this, however, leads me to suspect that this doesn't actually do what I want: I created a unity default plane, which has `11x11` vertices and 200 triangles (`10x10` pairs of squares), and the resolution of `hit.textureCoord` was clearly 0.1

It seems `textureCoord` is associated with the triangle and not the actual index in the material's basemap where there was a hit.

What I actually want to achieve is this: Given a `RaycastHit` I'd like to get the index on the material's basemap from which the point his is rendered (or, ideally, the value of the pixel at that index).

Every "solution" I find relies on `textureCoord` which clearly is not what I need.

One can assume my mesh is simply a flat plane with a single material attached.

The only solution I can come up with is assuming the plane is a square (which I would rather not, just to be able to generalize, even though in this specific case it is) to use
`hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point)`, make sure it is within the bounds of the mesh, find the size of the material's basemap, and figure out the index from that.